# PHP syntax for variable number of parameters to be passed to function pointer

Tags: php

May I ask is there a PHP way to write a variable number of parameters to a function pointer?

For example (psuedocode)

```
$args = $request->get_args(); // get an array of arguments
$request->$func_pointer(foreach $args write $arg);
```

My objective is to allow the API user to write functions with fixed number of parameters.
And later on pass the function name and the args which my API will execute on behalf.

Hope it is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array(array($request, $func_pointer), $args);
```

See [Manual `call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) for further information.

Comment: Thanks! this must be the hidden gems that only comes with usage experience.